# Three words that will help you throughout your day

Tags: riddle, rhyme, knowledge

> Add a letter to me, and you'll be thrown into medieval times,
> Take one away, and your stomach may be doing this.
> If you meet one like me, they will never commit any crimes.
> I can be used as the bare minimum, a near miss.
>
> I'm the the height of action, the very definition of it.
> Or I can be how someone styles their hair.
> The ability to perform, so you are not going to quit.
> With an e, and I become a female deer.
>
> Neither male or female, I'm neutral as can be.
> With an l, I'm cool and hot simultaneously.
> Be wary though, I'm a frightening movie,
> Add a couple letters, and I move spontaneously.

What am I?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I think the answer is

> Just Do It

such that

> Each verse corresponds to one of the words

Add a letter to me, and you'll be thrown into medieval times,

> Just $\rightarrow$ J**o**ust

Take one away, and your stomach may be doing this.

> Ju**s**t $\rightarrow$ Jut

If you meet one like me, they will never commit any crimes.

> A just person behaves according to what is morally right and fair.

I can be used as the bare minimum, a near miss.

> Just can mean barely or *by a little*.

I'm the the height of action, the very definition of it.

> Do, means to perform an action.

Or I can be how someone styles their hair.

> A *hair*do

The ability to perform, so you are not going to quit.

> Do means to achieve or complete.

With an e, and I become a female deer.

> Do $\rightarrow$ Do**e**

Neither male or female, I'm neutral as can be.

> "It" is a gender neutral pronoun

With an l, I'm cool and hot simultaneously.

> **L**it is slang for cool and can mean alight also.

Be wary though, I'm a frightening movie,

> [It](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/It_(2017_film)), the Stephen King novel and subsequent movie.

Add a couple letters, and I move spontaneously.

> It $\rightarrow$ It**ch**

Title

> It's three words long and is the motivational trademark of Nike.

Comment: Well, the last clue wasn't quite what I had in mind, but that's okay. Great job

Comment: Aww nuts. Sniped. I'm too slow at typing, I guess.

Answer (score 6):

You are

> Just Do It

Add a letter to me, and you'll be thrown into medieval times,

> J**o**ust is a kind of battle in medieval times.

Take one away, and your stomach may be doing this.

> Jut is what your belly might do if you stick it out.

If you meet one like me, they will never commit any crimes.

> A *just* person (as for *justice*) does not commit crimes.

I can be used as the bare minimum, a near miss.

> You can *just* achieve something.

I'm the the height of action, the very definition of it.

> Do

Or I can be how someone styles their hair.

> A hair*do*: *do* for short.

The ability to perform, so you are not going to quit.

> It's the definition of the verb *do*.

With an e, and I become a female deer.

> Do**e** a deer, a female deer (though technically in the song, they would be spelling it "do" as the note).

Neither male or female, I'm neutral as can be.

> *It* is not gendered.

With an l, I'm cool and hot simultaneously.

> Something that's **l**it is colloquially "cool" or could be on fire (hot).

Be wary though, I'm a frightening movie,

> *It* is a movie based on the book by Stephen King about a clown that eats kids. (I think that's what he did anyway. I forget.)

Add a couple letters, and I move spontaneously.

> **Tw**it**ch** is a spontaneous movement.

Comment: Excellent job, you got it right.

Comment: It's a bit more  complicated than just a clown eating kids, but +1 anyway :)

Answer (score 1):

I think you are

> **Do**.

---

`Add a letter to me, and you'll be thrown into medieval times,`

> Add the letter $\verb|v|$ to "do" and you can make "**dov**" which is short for [**Dover** Castle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dover_Castle).

`Take one away and your stomach may be doing this.`

> Now take **o**ne away (namely, the letter $\verb|o|$) from "dov" and you are left with "**dv**" which stands for **Dilatation Volvulus**. I have not provided a link as to what that actually is, because it can be quite disturbing to read about (especially for dogs...) but it happens in the stomach. 
>  
>  Perhaps you could also let it stand for **D**aily **V**alue, which is the percentage of nutrients in a type of food (because the nutrients travel toward your digestive system in your **stomach**).

`If you meet one like me, they will never commit any crimes.`

> A word like "do" is "**don't**", and "don't" **does not** commit crimes.

`I can be used as the bare minimum, a near miss.`

> The word "do" can be used as the bare minimum of a **catch phrase** during a near miss (metaphorically speaking). This is [Homer Simpson's](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homer_Simpson) catch phrase, "**do**h!" in the TV series, [The Simpsons](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Simpsons).

`I'm the height of action, the very definition of it.`

> **Do** means to carry out an **action** or some specific task.

`Or I can be how someone styles their hair.`

> When you **do** someone's hair, it means you can style it (though that is Aussie slang for [**making** someone's hair](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/328494/what-does-the-phrase-made-my-hair-generally-imply)).

`The ability to perform so you are not going to quit.`

> Described in the "height of action" line. But I think it is also a reference to ***Just Do It!***.

`With an e, and I become a female deer.`

> Add "e" to "do" and you get "**doe**", which is a female deer, even described in the lyric, [*"Do, a deer, a female deer..."*](http://www.metrolyrics.com/doremi-maria-and-the-children-lyrics-the-sound-of-music.html) (the "do" in the lyric is pronounced as "doe").

`Neither male nor female, I'm neutral as can be.`

> Apart from how the word "do" has a similar sound to "**dude**", it does not have any other affiliation with genders.

`With an I, I'm cool and hot simultaneously.`

> You can **feel** cool and hot on your wedding day before you have to say "**I do**" (note that the "I" has been added). Here are [$5$ emotions that you might feel during your wedding day](http://table6productions.com/5-emotions-every-bride-and-groom-feel-on-their-wedding-day/).

`Be wary though, I'm a frightening movie.`

> Ok, this is a bit of a stretch, but I am going to go back to the "Just Do It" quote. The word "**It**" is a frightening movie (thank you Stephen King). You can [check *it* out](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt1396484/) if you have not already seen *it*.

`Add a couple letters, and I move spontaneously.`

> If you add the letters $\verb|f|$, $\verb|t|$ and $\verb|h|$ to "it", you can make the word "**faith**" and there is a famous quote, *"faith can* ***move*** *mountains"*. Only problem is: it is *three* letters, and not a *couple*.

`What am I?`

> **Do**.

---

**Title:**

`Three words that will help you through your day.`

> ...I now feel like the answer might be **Just Do It**... hhmmmm....